# Rails: Forms_For new post calling different controller on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I've been working on a social site using the Rails framework. I just finished setting up a form and was able to submit a couple subposts. It worked for a bit, but now when I submit a subpost using forms_for(@subpost), it attempts to submit a completely different form on a separate view. No clue why it would call a separate form that hasn't even been rendered but hoping someone can help.

```
SubPost Controller
class SubPostsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @subpost = SubPost.new(sub_post_params)
        if @subpost.save
```

Form I want to submit

```
<%= form_for(@subpost) do |z| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: z.object %>
    <div class="field">
        <!--<input type="text" name="sub_post[user_id]" value="<%# current_user %>" style="display:none;"/>-->
        <input type="text" name="sub_post[micropost_id]" value="<%= micropost_id %>" style="display:none;"/>
        <%= z.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's on your mind?" %>
    </div>
    <%= z.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Updated to answer question

So basically I have my users personal page which displays their feed displaying a form under each post to submit a subpost. On the actual show page, there is no partial or render for post form, but that is what gets called each time I submit to the subpost form. The controller for the users page has two variables that I use to render the posts and subposts, @post = @user.posts.build and @subpost = @post.sub_posts.build

Comment: Can you show controller action in which your form is? Can you explain in detail what is happening and what you expect?

Comment: Made edits to answer your question @Mandeep

Comment: so you want to create a subpost for a particular post?

Comment: Correct. It was working before but is no longer working. The DB is a 1 to many setup and for each post I'm passing the post_id in a not so clean fashion

Comment: If you want to create a subpost for already created post then why are you building your post `@post = @user.posts.build`? This should be something like `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`

Comment: It's for the users page so I'm using a partial to render all posts from that user using @user as the association. I'm iterating through all the build posts of the user through that association so that's why I had it built like that but that makes sense to do it that way for the subpost

Comment: well then you need to change your UI design because your post is not created and you are trying to build a subpost for a post. Instead what you can do is create both post and subpost by using accepts_nested_attributes_for or just let a user create a post and then create a subpost on the show page of a post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61359/discussion-between-keith-v-and-mandeep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#some_controller.rb
def some_method
  @posts = Post.all
  SubPost.new
end
```

In your form you ***can use [`url option`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) to take form parameters to create action.*** Assuming your routes are nested you can do something like this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= form_for :subpost, url: some_path(@user, post) do |z| %>
    // you need to replace some_path(@user,post) by your path helper
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: z.object %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= z.hidden_field :post_id, value: post.id %>
      <%= z.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's on your mind?" %>
    </div>
    <%= z.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```